# simple tax_query intersection

Tags: tax-query, multi-taxonomy-query

I'm trying to do tax_query for posts that have a term1 in taxonomy1 AND a term2 in taxonomy2

if I do:

```
'tax_query' => [
  'relation' => 'AND',
  [
    'taxonomy'         => 'taxonomy1',
    'terms'            => 'term1',
  ],
  [
    'taxonomy'         => 'taxonomy2',
    'terms'            => 'term2',
  ],
],
```

I get all post with term1 in taxonomy1 AND all post with term2 in taxonomy2. I want the posts containing both terms: term1 and term2.

Thank you.

**[EDIT. ACTUAL CODE]**

First, I recover al terms of "link-category" and pass it to the template:

```
public function links()
{
    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'link-category',
        'hide_empty' =>true,
        ));
    return $terms;
}
```

https://github.com/aitormendez/superbiajuridico/blob/master/web/app/themes/sj/app/Controllers/App.php#L19-L26

Then, in the template, I loop it with foreach:

https://github.com/aitormendez/superbiajuridico/blob/master/web/app/themes/sj/resources/views/partials/footer.blade.php#L14-L28

```
    @if (!empty($links))
      @foreach ($links as $link)
        <div class="col bloque py-3">
        @php
        $args = [
          'post_type'              => ['links'],
          'post_status'            => 'publish',
          'tax_query'              => [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            [
              'taxonomy'         => 'link-category',
              'terms'            => $link,
            ],
            [
              'taxonomy'         => 'despacho',
              'terms'            => $despacho,
            ],
          ],
        ];
        $link_posts = new WP_Query($args);
        @endphp
        @if ($link_posts->have_posts())
          <h3>{{ $link->name }}</h3>
          <ul>
          @while ($link_posts->have_posts()) @php $link_posts->the_post();
            $link = get_field('url') @endphp
            <li>
              <a href="{{ $link['url'] }}" target="{{ $link['target'] }}"> {{ $link['title'] }}</a>
            </li>
          @endwhile
          </ul>
        @endif
        </div>
      @endforeach
    @endif
```

This code collects a CPT called "link" to show it in the footer of this page: https://stage.superbiajuridico.es/

This is the look of the footer:

[image: footer]

Comment: That should be the result of your example code. What's the _actual_ code that's not giving you the result you expect?

Comment: To second JP's comment, sample code is helpful but actual code often reveals the issue.  I wonder if you are leaving out the `field` parameter in your tax queries as well.  Field will default to term_id if not explicitly defined.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I'll go to update the question with more info.

Comment: As @jdm2112 pointed, if the `$link` and `$despacho` are term *slugs* and not IDs, then you should add `'field' => 'slug'` to your tax query clauses. But if that's not the case, then you can inspect the SQL for that query: `echo $link_posts->request;` - what's the output? And btw, the GitHub links in the question are pointing to 404 error..

Comment: It works! Double apologies: I didn't understand the field indication the first time. And the github repository is now open. Thank you very much for the help and attention. This is an outstanding community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jdm2112 and SallyCJ said in the comments, the query lacks of `'field' => 'slug'`. So:

```
'tax_query' => [
  'relation' => 'AND',
  [
    'taxonomy'         => 'link-category',
    'terms'            => $link,
    'field'            => 'slug'
  ],
  [
    'taxonomy'         => 'despacho',
    'terms'            => $despacho,
    'field'            => 'slug'
  ],
],
```